# Scroll bar not appearing?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, tumblr

I'm developing a theme for Tumblr and the scrollbar isn't appearing for some reason? [This is the url for the blog.](http://infinitethemedewitt.tumblr.com/)

The code for the theme can be found on the page source from the right click (all but the html as it gets messed up by Tumblr filling in the `{}` blanks)

```
<body>
<div id="titlebox">
<div id="title"><b>{Title}</b><div>
{block:IfHeaderImage}<img src="{image:Header}" class="avatar"/>{/block:IfHeaderImage}
<div id="description">{Description}</div>
{block:Pages}{block:HasPages}<div id="pages"><a href="{URL}" class="pagelabel">{Label}</a><br></div>{/block:HasPages}{block:Pages}
</div>
</div>
<div id="postholder">
{block:Posts}
<div id="post">
{block:Photo}<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="PhotoAlt" class="photo"></a>{/block:Photo}
{block:Text}{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}{Body}{/block:Text}
</div>
{/block:Posts}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theme is in a way the the height is small therefore the scroll bar disappears.
If you have to have a scroll bar try this by adding it under the `<style type="text/css">` tag :

```
html {
    height: 110%;
    margin-bottom: 0.01em;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
body {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few funny things going on here.

'sidebar' has position 'fixed', which prevents the any new content from being seen even with overflow: auto.

What you can do is remove position: fixed from 'sidebar' and 'postholder'. give 'postholder' overflow: scroll and set body's overflow: auto to hidden (this removes the second scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

```
    html, body{
      overflow:initial !important;
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!