# Scrollbar of modal window: Why is it invisible allthaugh being enabled?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm having a similar problem to this here:[Scroll bar not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688423/scroll-bar-not-appearing). My scrollbar is enabled using the comment `overflow : auto`. It's also working perfectly fine, if I use the top and down arrows on my keyboard. However the scrollbar is not visible on my modal window. I tried `overflow-y: scroll` as well as `overflow-scroll`.Didn't help. Any ideas whatelse I could try?

Comment: This is potentially and OS setting, does the scrollbar appear when you start to scroll?

Comment: @BrettEast, the problem is varying accross browsers: on firefox no problem. on chrome, which I use most times it doesnt show up at all but i can move up and down with arrows. opera is same as chrome. and on microsoft edge l can see the scroll bar,but it doesnt react to clicks but lets scrolling using the arrow buttons.

Comment: No worries armel, it's probably a browser setting mixed with an operating system setting. I'm using a mac, and haven't seen scrollbars in years. I'm quite sure that this is not an html/css issue that you're having, but one with browser/os, in fact I bet if I viewed your site in any of the browsers on my own computer, I wouldn't see a scroll bar. Having said that, check out this https://appuals.com/fix-chrome-scrollbar-disappears/ - it might help

Comment: @BrettEast, ok that's relieving. Thanks for the link!